# Want to restructure/modify the API response for required JSON format in Angular project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

The API response needs to change in the required JSON format as below. I have mentioned the responses that I am getting.. and also I mentioned the desired format.  Please guide me.

It listed the person's data. but I need the persons should be grouped based on department.

**The response want I am getting is**

```
    {
   "statusCode":200,
   "message":"OK",
   "status":"success",
   "response":{
      "data":[
         {
            "name":"John",
            "age":30,
            "department":"Hardware"
         },
         {
            "name":"Durai",
            "age":22,
            "department":"Hardware"
         },
         {
            "name":"Durai",
            "age":22,
            "department":"Software"
         },
         {
            "name":"Durai",
            "age":22,
            "department":"Software"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**I want to change the above response into the format like below,**

```
    {
   "statusCode":200,
   "message":"OK",
   "status":"success",
   "response":{
      "data":{
         "department":"Hardware",
         "persons":[
            {
               "name":"John",
               "age":30,
               "department":"Hardware"
            },
            {
               "name":"Durai",
               "age":22,
               "department":"Hardware"
            }
         ]
      },
      "department":"Hardware",
      "persons":[
         {
            "name":"Durai",
            "age":22,
            "department":"Software"
         },
         {
            "name":"Durai",
            "age":22,
            "department":"Software"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: how did it go? Did my answer provide any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of approaching it...

```js
let orig_data = [{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "department": "Hardware"
  },
  {
    "name": "Durai",
    "age": 22,
    "department": "Hardware"
  },
  {
    "name": "Durai",
    "age": 22,
    "department": "Software"
  },
  {
    "name": "Durai",
    "age": 22,
    "department": "Software"
  }
]

let data = [];
orig_data.forEach(el => {
// check to see if we already have a new object ready for this department...
  if (data.filter(el2 => el2.department == el.department).length == 0) {
  // we don't, so create it and start the persons array
    data.push({
      department: el.department,
      persons: [el]
    })
  } else {
  // we do, so find it and add another person
    data.forEach(el3 => {
      if (el3.department == el.department) el3.persons.push(el);
    })
  }
})

console.log(data)
```